# Avoiding instanceof and cast, does a Super Class can know children class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, instanceof

I have this kind of code using instanceof and cast and i want to avoid them :

```
class Vehicle {}

class Boat extends Vehicle {
    getFloating()
}

class Car extends Vehicle{
    getWheels()
}

class UseVehicle{
    void useVehicleAsCar(Vehicle vehicle){ 
// this method cant be change its parameter Vehicle, of course ;D

        if (vehicle instanceof Car){
           ((Car)vehicle).getWheels() 
        }
    }
}
```

A solution can be the following :

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    Car asCar(){return null;}
    Boat asBoat(){return null;}
}

class Boat extends Vehicle {
    getFloating(){};
    Boat asBoat(){return this};

}

class Car extends Vehicle{
    getWheels(){}
    Car asCar(){return this;}
}

class UseVehicle{
    void useVehicleAsCar(Vehicle vehicle){ 
// accept in exemple that object param is an instance of Car

        vehicle.asCar().getWheels(); 
    }
}
```

But now the vehicle class know children .... and If i want to had a Bus class i have to add method in super Class

Do you have something better?

Comment: From what you've posted, `Vehicle` seems to have no reason to exist. Are you perhaps using abstraction for the wrong reasons?

Comment: the real code is a lot more complexe, Vehicle and UseVehicle are from an other project Interface i can't delete them ;) 
I can modify the content of Vehicle and useVehicleAsCar

Comment: Considering `UseVehicle`, will you have one method per subclass? i.e., will there be `useVehicleAsBoat` and so on? Or, will there be one method where you want to call a method (`getWheels` or `getFloating`) based on the concrete type of the vehicle passed?

Comment: Do you have `Car` and `Boat` both are `Vehicle` and do you need that a client class `UseVehicle` receive a `Vehicle` and know some details from the Child classes?

Comment: Just create an abstract method `use()` inside your `Vehicle` and implement it inside concrete classes, then use that abstract method inside your `UseVehicle`. Another option might be creating parametrized UseVehicle.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution here is to get rid of the `Vehicle` class. It defines no common contract between `Car` and `Boat`.

In other words, the relationship of `Vehicle` to its subclasses is not much more useful than that of `java.lang.Object` to those same subclasses.

---

Now, given that you cannot change the signature of `useVehicleAsCar`, you have no choice but to check the runtime class of the argument in that method's implementation.
You could have been able to overload this method with specific subtypes, but this seems to be obviously out of question since you have `Vehicle` as parameter for a reason (the same one for which you can't change it).

There are of course many undesirable ways to check the concrete type of the argument, and which one is chosen becomes primarily a matter of preference. *I* would stick with `instanceof`, because it, compared to the `asBoat`/`asCar` alternative, remains clear and keeps the "contract" of `Vehicle` rather free of (even more) unnecessary concepts.